# GCM not working in Background - Swift

Tags: c#, swift

I need to show GCM notification when my app in background .

C# Server Code to send Notificaiton message to ios device :

```
 public string SendNotification(string apiKey, string token, string _postData)
    {
        try
        {

        string tickerText = "Desert Vessel";

        string SERVER_API_KEY = apiKey;
        var SENDER_ID = "0000....";
        string regIds = string.Join("\",\"", token);

        NotificationMessage nm = new NotificationMessage();
        nm.Title = tickerText;
        nm.Message = _postData;
        nm.ItemId = 1;

        var value = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(nm);

        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", SERVER_API_KEY));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "{\"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"priority\" : \"high\"  ,\"time_to_live\":108,\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"data\": { \"message\" : " + value + ",\"time\": " + "\"" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\"},\"registration_ids\":[\"" + regIds + "\"]}";

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

and Swift Code  :

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate, GCMReceiverDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let core = Settings()
    var connectedToGCM = false
    var subscribedToTopic = false
    var gcmSenderID: String?
    var registrationToken: String?
    var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

    let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
    let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
    let subscriptionTopic = "/topics/global"

    // [START register_for_remote_notifications]
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
        [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
            // the services that have entries in the file
            var configureError:NSError?
            GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
            assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
            gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            // Register for remote notifications

            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


            // [END register_for_remote_notifications]
            // [START start_gcm_service]
            let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
            gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
            GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)
            // [END start_gcm_service]
            return true
    }

    func subscribeToTopic() {
        // If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to subscribe to the
        // topic
        if(registrationToken != nil && connectedToGCM) {
            GCMPubSub.sharedInstance().subscribeWithToken(self.registrationToken, topic: subscriptionTopic,
                options: nil, handler: {(error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Treat the "already subscribed" error more gently
                        if error.code == 3001 {
                            print("Already subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)")
                        } else {
                            print("Subscription failed: \(error.localizedDescription)");
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.subscribedToTopic = true;
                        NSLog("Subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)");
                    }
            })
        }
    }

    // [START connect_gcm_service]
    func applicationDidBecomeActive( application: UIApplication) {
        // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
        GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({(error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.connectedToGCM = true
                print("Connected to GCM")
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                self.subscribeToTopic()
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        })
    }
    // [END connect_gcm_service]

    // [START disconnect_gcm_service]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        self.connectedToGCM = false
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END disconnect_gcm_service]

    // [START receive_apns_token]
    func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
        deviceToken: NSData ) {
            // [END receive_apns_token]
            // [START get_gcm_reg_token]
            // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
            let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
            instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
            // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
            // token to enable reception of notifications
            GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
            registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
            GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
                scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
            // [END get_gcm_reg_token]
    }

    // [START receive_apns_token_error]
    func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
        error: NSError ) {
            print("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            // [END receive_apns_token_error]
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }

    // [START ack_message_reception]
    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
            print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
            if let info = userInfo as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                if let aps = info["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, String> {
                    var arr =  aps["alert"]!.characters.split{$0 == "-"}.map(String.init)
                    core.setCookie("Trucking", value: arr[0] )
                    core.setCookie("Company", value: arr[1])
                }
            }

            // This works only if the app started the GCM service
            GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Handle the received message
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }

    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
            // This works only if the app started the GCM service
            GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Handle the received message
            // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
            handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END ack_message_reception]

    func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            self.registrationToken = registrationToken
            print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
            self.subscribeToTopic()
            let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
            core.setCookie("token",value: registrationToken)
        } else {
            print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
            core.setCookie("token",value: "error")
        }
    }

    // [START on_token_refresh]
    func onTokenRefresh() {
        // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
        print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    }
    // [END on_token_refresh]

    // [START upstream_callbacks]
    func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Failed to send the message.
        } else {
            // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
        }
    }

    func didSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!) {
        // Did successfully send message identified by messageID
    }
    // [END upstream_callbacks]

    func didDeleteMessagesOnServer() {
        // Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
        // because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
        // server can resend those messages.
    }

}
```

---

I didn't know where is the problem and how to fix it.

Note : Message came to ios device but notification didn't show
       i saw it in debug screen.
When i add 'content_available: true' to Http Post in c# the server return "Internal Error"

Comment: What exactly did you see in the debug screen?

Comment: I saw the message that i sent it from Web API when app is running . But notification didn't show when app in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I changed this line and everything was OK.
```

string postData = "{\"notification\": { \"body\" : " + value + " , \"badge\" : \"1\", \"sound\" : \"default\"},\"to\":\"" + regIds + "\" , \"content_available\":true , \"priority\" : \"high\"}";